Do Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives and Pareto optimality imply monotonicity whenever there are Condorcet winners?
I am trying to show that independence of irrelevant alternatives and Pareto optimality imply monotonicity in the restricted strict preference domain with Condorcet winners. I am looking for any of these things:

a counter-example that proves my conjecture wrong,
a proof strategy to show my conjecture,
a helpful reference.

Let $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$ be a finite set of voters; let $A=\{1,\dots,a\}$ be a finite set of alternatives, where $a\geq 3$; let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all linear orders on $A$; let $\mathcal{C}^N\subsetneq\mathcal{P}^N$ be the set of all linear order profiles with Condorcet winners, where an alternative $x\in A$ is a Condorcet winner at profile $\mathbf{P}\in\mathcal{P}^N$ if and only if $\{i\in N\mid xP_iy\}>n/2$ for all alternatives $y\in A\backslash\{x\}$; and let $f:\mathcal{C}^N\to\mathcal{P}$ be a social welfare function.

A social welfare function $f:\mathcal{C}^N\to\mathcal{P}$ is independent of irrelevant alternatives if and only if given any two alternatives $x,y\in A$ and any two profiles $\mathbf{P},\mathbf{P}'\in\mathcal{C}^N$ such that for all voters $i\in N$, we have $xP_iy$ if and only if $xP_i'y$; then we also have $xf(\mathbf{P})y$ if and only if $xf(\mathbf{P}')y$.

A social welfare function $f:\mathcal{C}^N\to\mathcal{P}$ is Pareto optimal if and only if for all profiles $\mathbf{P}\in\mathcal{C}^N$ and all alternatives $x,y\in A$, we have that $xP_iy$ for all voters $i\in N$ implies that $xf(\mathbf{P})y$.


Given any profile $\mathbf{P}\in\mathcal{C}^N$ and any alternative $x\in A$, let $L_i(x,\mathbf{P})=\{y\in A\mid xP_iy\}$ be voter $i$'s lower contour set at $x$, and let $\mathcal{C}^N(\mathbf{P},x)=\{\mathbf{P}'\in\mathcal{C}^N\mid(\forall i\in N)[L_i(x,\mathbf{P})\subseteq L_i(x,\mathbf{P}')]\}$ be the set of preference profiles in which alternative $x$ has not fallen in any voter's preference.

A social welfare function $f:\mathcal{C}^N\to\mathcal{P}$ is monotonic if and only if for all alternatives $x\in A$, all profiles $\mathbf{P}\in\mathcal{C}^N$ and all profiles $\mathbf{P}'\in\mathcal{C}^N(\mathbf{P},x)$; we have that for all alternatives $y\in A\backslash\{x\}$, $xf(\mathbf{P})y$ implies $xf(\mathbf{P}')y$.

By Arrow (1950), we know that under the unrestricted strict preference domain, a social welfare function satisfying Pareto optimality and independence of irrelevant alternatives is dictatorial, and thus monotonic. My feeling by reading contemporary versions of Arrow’s (1950) proof is that the unrestricted domain is necessary to attain the dictatorial result, but not monotonicity. However, I cannot prove it nor find a counter-example.
Can you provide any help?

Here is a partial answer that assumes $a\geq 4$. The main point is that the existence of a Condorcet winner doesn't do that much in this setting.
Let $x$ be any alternative, and let $\mathcal{C}_x$ be the set of linear orders that rank $x$ top.  Then, any profile of linear orders over the remaining $a-1$ alternatives corresponds to a unique profile in $\mathcal{C}_x^N$. Moreover, a Condorcet winner always exists, namely $x$. Every social welfare function defined on profiles of linear orders over the remaining $a-1$ alternatives that satisfy the conditions must clearly extend to a unique social welfare function on $\mathcal{C}_x^N$. So a dictator over these $a-1$ alternatives exists by Arrow's theorem. Since this works for all $x$, a plain dictator must exist too.
